# Why the sequence of SASS @mixin does't matter?

Tags: sass

If the @mixin is defined after the rule, there will be an error:

> Error: Undefined mixin 'parent'.

```
.child {
  @include parent();
}

@mixin parent() {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But if mixin2 is defined after the mixin1, there is no error, **why is this?**

```
@mixin parent() {
  @include parent2();
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@mixin parent2() {
  margin: 1px;
}

.child {
  @include parent();
}
```

---

And the same for the variables:

```
.child {
  margin: $variable1;
}

$variable1 : 1px;
```

This produces an error:

> Error: Undefined variable: "$variable1".

But this won't

```
@mixin parent() {
  margin: $variable1;
}

$variable1 : 1px;

.child {
  @include parent();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Defining vs Using**

When you compiled below `scss` to `css` no code will be generated, because `mixin` doesn't get compiled until you use it.

```
@mixin parent() {
  @include parent2();
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@mixin parent2() {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

and when you do this

```
.child {
  @include parent();
}
```

It will look for `mixin` to generate css while compiling.

> In your first case it throws error because `.child` needs to compile,
>   and in second case it did not because mixin never gets compiled until you
>   use it

**This is the reason we declare `mixin`/`variables` or import `mixin`/`variables` file before using it.**

Hope I answered your question!